# Achieving this hr element with CSS styling - pseudo elements

Tags: css, pseudo-element

I'm having some difficulty finding a solution to style a hr element to my preference.

If you look at the following fiddle you will see the hr element has both :before and :after pseudos added to it.

http://jsfiddle.net/MattStrange/LGEjp/

So far this is what i want, both circles on either side is correct but now i want to add an image to the exact center of the line, but because both pseudos are taken up i'm not sure how to add a background image to this hr.

```
<hr class="bolt">
```

```css
hr {
  border: 0 solid #eeedef;
  border-top-width: 1px;
  height: 0;
  margin-top: 60px;
  margin-bottom: 60px;
  float: left;
  clear: both;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
hr:before, hr:after {
  content: " ";
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
  background-color: #fff;
}
hr:before {
  left: 0;
  bottom: -3px;
}
hr:after {
  bottom: -3px;
  right: 0;
}
```

Help very much appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use :

1. one pseudo to draw the 2 rounds, first round is drawn with borders,
   the second  is its shadow.
2. another pseudo to bring in the image.

http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/dHaus

```css
hr {
  border: 0 solid #eeedef;
  border-top-width: 1px;
  height: 0;
  margin: 60px auto;
  clear: both;
  display: block;
  width: 400px;
  position: relative;
}
hr:before {
  content: " ";
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  background-color: #999;
}
hr:before {
  left: 0;
  bottom: -3px;
box-shadow: 400px 0 0 -1px #999, 400px 0 0 0 #aaa;
}
hr:after {
  content:url(http://lorempixel.com/50/50/cats/2);
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  left:50%;
  height:50px;
  width:50px;
  margin:-25px 0 0 -25px;
  border-radius:50px;
  overflow:hidden;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #eef, 0 0 5px;
}
 
body {background:#789}
```

```html
<hr/>
```

Comment: Excellent! Almost exactly what i'm after, is it possible to set the hr element to 100% in width and the `box-shadow: 400px 0 0 -1px white, 400px 0 0 0 #eeedef` to 100%?