# Multiple dots on <hr />

Tags: css

I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17182245/achieving-this-hr-element-with-css-styling-pseudo-elements) link and using the code, i could successfully achieve this. 
My requirement is to keep multiple dots on the line at 25%, 30%... so on dynamically. These values come from a database. [image]

Wondering how to achieve this.

Comment: That doesn't sound like an appropriate use of an `hr`. What is the purpose of the dynamic indicator? Sounds more like a `progress` element to me, https://css-tricks.com/html5-progress-element/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [css: how to make circles connected by lines responsive with bootstrap?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25340472/css-how-to-make-circles-connected-by-lines-responsive-with-bootstrap)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code to do this via **svg** is fairly straight forward.

```css
#lineWithDots {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20;
}

#lineWithDots rect {
  width: 100%;
  stroke: rgb(164, 188, 194);
}

#lineWithDots circle {
  stroke: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  fill: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
```

```html
<svg id="lineWithDots">
  <g transform="translate(0,10)">
    <rect height="2" y="-1" />
    <circle r="4" cx="35%" />
    <circle r="4" cx="85%" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: i never knew its so simple with SVG. ok, how can i create them in runtime may be using jquery?

Comment: That would be an entirely separate question, first search for existing solutions, try to create a solution yourself and then, if nothing turns up or your solution doesn't work, [ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).